# Animation rotation off axis

Tags: android-animation, android

I'm trying to create a custom "loading/throbber" icon for my app.  I have an ImageView that points to my "loading" icon:

[image: loading con]

The problem is the rotation is off axis and looks "wobbly", but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong:

```
    <ImageView 
       android:id="@+id/headerReload"
       android:src="@drawable/reload" 
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:paddingRight="5dip"
       android:onClick="headerReload_onClick"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    />

    public void headerReload_onClick(final View v) {
        ImageView searchSpinner = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.headerReload);
        Animation spinnerAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.loading);
        searchSpinner.startAnimation(spinnerAnimation);             
    }
```

loading.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rotate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:duration="1200" 
/>
```

Comment: I'm not sure but could it be because you have a padding of  5dp on the right side? Just an idea

Comment: ha! that was totally it. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help, I'll put it as an answer so you can close out the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

5dp padding on the right side will cause it to rotate unevenly